# How to log jasper report logs to separate log file?

Tags: java, logging, jasper-reports, log4j

I am new to JasperReport and Log4j, Now I have to Log all log messages related to jasper report to a new log file. As of now it writes to log file and console bit I want it to log only on separate log file. How can achive this.

Here is my log4j.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%c{1}] %-5p :%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/ITS_Server.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%c{1}] %-5p:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<category name="org.hibernate">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
</category>

<category name="java.sql">
    <priority value="debug" />
</category>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />

    <appender-ref ref="file" />


</root> -->

</log4j:configuration>
```

Please Anyone can help me in this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define a new appender:

```
<appender name="jasper" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/jasperReports.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%c{1}] %-5p:%L - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

And a new category with have the apender as reference:

```
<category additivity="false"  name="net.sf.jasperreports">
    <priority value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="jasper"/>
</category>
```

Comment: Thank you very much . but here I cannot log Hibernate INFO logs to a file , How can I do that . can you please tell about any changes I have to make in this.

Comment: @Raghu will you log the hibernate messages to the same file as the messages of jasperreports?

Comment: Yes I did but its not logging , look at my code  `<category name="org.hibernate">
  <priority value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
 </category>`

Comment: @Raghu the code looks fine. It should be write the messages to `ITS_Server.log`

Comment: All logs I write in Servlets are log to `ITS_Server.log` but not Hibernate startup INFO logs.

Comment: k . .  and can we do this in root `<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" /><level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" /><appender-ref ref="console" />
 </root>` I mean Debug messeges has to be write to file and error messages to both file and console

Comment: Your solution worked but problem is resport logs are logging in both log files `ITS_Server.log` and `jasperReports.log`. I want this to be in JasperReport.log

Comment: @Raghu No but you can do somthing like that: `<root> <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" /><level value="DEBUG" />
</root>` and then add` <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>` to your consoleAppender.

Comment: @Raghu I have changed my answer. Added `additivity="false"` to the category. Now the logging in ITS_Server.log for alll jasperReport messages should gone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75900/discussion-between-raghu-and-jens).